# My values in spring boot table row is getting erased

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am making a medicine application where I am adding medicine id, medicine name, and more. Here I have a column called **Medicine Quantity** which shows how much of which medicine is left in my stock and **Medicine Quantity Sold** shows how much of that medicine is sold.
What I wanted to achieve was that, taking a number as input from user for a specific medicine, compare with its medicine quantity, if less, then reduce the quantity of medicine in stock. For eg: if i have 90 in stock, and user entered 10. Since 10 is less than 90, those many medicine can be sold. So 90-10 = 80. So after selling, my medicine quantity is 80. But I am not able to achieve it. Can someone help? Because when I am executing my SellMedicine.html, excluding m_id, all values are vanishing.

MedCRUD.java

```
package bootbeanfiles;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

//Hibernate Entity
@Entity
@Table(name="medicine")

public class MedCRUD {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "med_id")
    Integer m_id;
    @Column(name = "med_name", length = 40)
    String mname;
    @Column(name = "med_price")
    Integer mprice;
    @Column(name = "med_quantityL")
    Integer mquantity;
    @Column(name = "med_qaantityS")
    Integer mquantitys;
    @Column(name = "med_pricesold")
    Integer mpricesold;
    public Integer getM_id() {
        return m_id;
    }
    public void setM_id(Integer m_id) {
        this.m_id = m_id;
    }
    public String getMname() {
        return mname;
    }
    public void setMname(String mname) {
        this.mname = mname;
    }
    public Integer getMprice() {
        return mprice;
    }
    public void setMprice(Integer mprice) {
        this.mprice = mprice;
    }
    public Integer getMquantity() {
        return mquantity;
    }
    public void setMquantity(Integer mquantity) {
        this.mquantity = mquantity;
    }
    public Integer getMquantitys() {
        return mquantitys;
    }
    public void setMquantitys(Integer mquantitys) {
        this.mquantitys = mquantitys;
    }
    public Integer getMpricesold() {
        return mpricesold;
    }
    public void setMpricesold(Integer mpricesold) {
        this.mpricesold = mpricesold;
    }
}
```

Medicine_Repository

```
package repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import bootbeanfiles.MedCRUD;

public interface Medicine_Repository extends JpaRepository<MedCRUD, Integer>{

}
```

MedService.java

```
package doaservicelayer;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import bootbeanfiles.MedCRUD;
import repository.Medicine_Repository;

/*
 * In Service layer, you do all the CRUD operations and all.... like selecrt 
 */
@Service
public class MedService {
    @Autowired
    private Medicine_Repository repo;
    
    public List<MedCRUD> listall()
    {
        return repo.findAll();
    }
    
    public void p_save(MedCRUD medicine)
    {
        repo.save(medicine); //inserting medicine
    }
    
    public MedCRUD p_get(int id)
    {
        return repo.findById(id).get();
    }
    
    public void p_delete(int id)
    {
        repo.deleteById(id);
    }
    
    public void sell(int id, int quantity, MedCRUD medicine)
    {
        if(repo.findById(id).get().getMquantity() >= quantity)
        {
            repo.findById(id).get().setMquantity(repo.findById(id).get().getMquantity() - quantity);
            repo.save(medicine);
        }
                
    }

}
```

MedCRUDController.java

```
package bootcontroller;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import bootbeanfiles.MedCRUD;
import doaservicelayer.MedService;

@Controller
public class MedCRUDController {
    
    @Autowired
    MedService service;
    
    //Insert
    @RequestMapping("/newm")
    public String showNewMedicinePage(Model model)
    {
        MedCRUD medicine = new MedCRUD();
        model.addAttribute("medicine", medicine);
        return "AddMedicine"; //Addmedicine.html using thymeleaf
    }
    
    //Select
    @RequestMapping("/m")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model)
    {
        List<MedCRUD> medicinelist = service.listall();
        model.addAttribute("medicinelist" ,medicinelist);
        
        return "ViewMedicine"; //ViewMedicine.html
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/savem", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveMedicine(@ModelAttribute("medicine") MedCRUD medicine)
    {
        service.p_save(medicine);
        return "redirect:/m"; //@RequestMapping("/")=>ViewMedicine.html
    }
    
    //Update
    @RequestMapping("/edit_medicine/{m_id}")
    public ModelAndView showEditMedicinePage(@PathVariable(name = "m_id") int med_id)
    {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("EditMedicine"); //EditMedicine.html
        MedCRUD med = service.p_get(med_id);
        mav.addObject("medicine", med);
        return mav;
    }
    
    //Delete
    @RequestMapping("/delete_medicine/{m_id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name = "m_id") int med_id)
    {
        service.p_delete(med_id);
        return "redirect:/m"; //@RequestMapping("/")=>ViewMedicine.html
    }
    
    //Sell
    @RequestMapping("/sell_medicine/{m_id}")
    public ModelAndView Sell(@PathVariable(name = "m_id") int med_id)
    {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("SellMedicine"); //SellMedicine.html
        MedCRUD med = service.p_get(med_id);
        mav.addObject("medicine", med);
        return mav;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sell", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showEditMedicineQuantity(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("medicine") MedCRUD medicine)
    {
        //service.p_get(med_id);
        service.sell(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("m_id")), Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity")), medicine);
        service.p_save(medicine);
        //saveMedicine(medicine);
        return "redirect:/m";
    }
    
    

}
```

SellMedicine.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sell Medicine here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>Sell Medicine</h1>
        <br>
        <form action = "#" th:action = "@{/sell}" th:object = "${medicine}" method = "post"> 
        <!--<form action = "/sell" method = "post"> -->
            <table  border = "2" cellpadding = "10" bgcolor = "lightblue">
                <tr>
                    <td>Medicine ID:</td>
                    <td><input type = "text" name = "m_id"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter the Quantity you wanna buy:</td>
                    <td><input type = "text" name = "quantity" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan = "2"><button type = "submit">Save</button> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are saving your CRUD object multiple times:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sell", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showEditMedicineQuantity(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("medicine") MedCRUD medicine)
{
    //service.p_get(med_id);
    service.sell(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("m_id")), Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity")), medicine);
    service.p_save(medicine);
    //saveMedicine(medicine);
    return "redirect:/m";
}
```

service.sell edits and saves the new quantity to the database. Then immediately after that, you're calling p_save which will overwrite that medicine with the original CRUD instance.

Try something like this:

```
public void sell(int id, int quantity, MedCRUD medicine)
{
    if(medicine.getMquantity() >= quantity)
    {
        medicine.setMquantity(medicine.getMquantity() - quantity);
        repo.save(medicine);
    }   
}
```